# Zope Mailhost mailqueue

Tags: email, zope

I'm using the Mailhost object in Zope to send emails from forms or scripts in different websites, with the "Use mail queue" setting set.
In the last weeks, I began experiencing problems with lots of emails not being sent but remaining in the mailqueue folder.

I'm not sure what's the cause, probably some problems with the used smtp servers (some mails get sent, some don't), but that's not the question I'm about to ask.

I'd like to know if there is a way of manually resending (or trying to) the timed-out mails in the mailqueue folder.

Comment: Are you sure your mail queue processor thread is running?  In ZMI, should look like this: http://snag.gy/d5V6E.jpg

Comment: Yes, the thread is running.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem: I always wondered, why the older messages in the queue aren't sent later and I assumed they time out. But I used several MailHost objects in different Zope instances with one mailqueue folder, so the files were stuck because several processes tried to access them (I guess that was the case). Creating one mailqueue folder per Mailhost did resolve my problem.

Comment: That is strange; there is a mechanism in zope.sendmail that should, in theory, prevent any concurrency issues (IIRC temp file is touched to bump the file date so that even if one queue processor thread/process starts working on a message, and another one does as well, the first one always wins).